# Interpreting SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql

So, I need to use PHP to pull out field names and values from the where statement of a sql query, change them, then put the thing back together.

So, say I'm given this string: `field='value' AND field2<7` I need to recognize field and field2 as field names, then feed then through the function `field()` and put them back into the query. Same things with 'value' and 7, but feed them through a `value()` function. It would also help to know what field each value was associated with.

Is there any way to do this that won't take a few thousand lines to code?

I need it to work with a lot of different possible inputs, including things like: `table.field BETWEEN 7 AND 10` or `field<7 AND (field2=3 OR field3=4)`

Comment: Do you need something re-usable or can you just modify it with string replacements?

Comment: What is the context? If the domain is limited, you could use a regular expression. If you need to work with any arbitrary query, you'll need to use an SQL parser.

Comment: It needs to work for a wide variety of possible inputs, if you can do it with string replacements that would work, but I think its more complex than string replacements will allow for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used the [php-sql-parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/) project which is open source and pretty good.

Comment: Is it able to parse SQL quickly? Time is an issue here, it would be a problem if it took a few seconds per query.

Comment: I don't know.  You would have to do some profiling in your application to see if it's fast enough for your business needs.

Comment: The example script provided on the site has a speed tester. Here are the parse times I achieved with that `example.php`: **Simple query 0.0025022029876709 seconds** , **Very somewhat simple statement 0.0020349025726318 seconds** , **Highly complex statement 0.025777816772461 seconds**